# Hash large file using little memory

Tags: go, memory, hash, memory-leaks

I need to hash very large files (>10TB files). So I decided to hash 128KB per MB.
My idea is to divide the file into 1MB blocks and hash only the first 128KB of each block.

The following code works, but it uses insane amounts of memory and I can't tell why...

```
func partialMD5Hash(filePath string) string {
    var blockSize int64 = 1024 * 1024
    var sampleSize int64 = 1024 * 128

    file, err := os.Open(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        return "ERROR"
    }
    defer file.Close()
    fileInfo, _ := file.Stat()
    fileSize := fileInfo.Size()

    hash := md5.New()

    var i int64
    for i = 0; i < fileSize / blockSize; i++ {
        sample := make([]byte, sampleSize)
        _, err = file.Read(sample)
        if err != nil {
            return "ERROR"
        }
        hash.Write(sample)

        _, err := file.Seek(blockSize-sampleSize, 1)
        if err != nil {
            return "ERROR"
        }
    }

    return hex.EncodeToString(hash.Sum(nil))
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: you are allocating that much data on the heap. cluttering the GC. slowing down your process. eating up your memory.

Comment: @mh-cbon how could I avoid it?

Comment: see Burak Serdar answer.

Comment: @mh-cbon If you read the comments you would know that his post is not the answer. Although I took the sample out of the loop, it's still showing the same behavior.

Comment: Consider that, maybe, this was not the origin of the problem to begin with.

Comment: You should consider versioning instead of getting a hash. Or use the create/change date that your FS offers.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with the approach, and with the program.

If you want to hash a large file, you have to hash all of it. Sampling parts of the file will not detect modifications to the parts you didn't sample.

You are allocating a new buffer for every iteration. Instead, allocate one buffer outside the for-loop, and reuse it.

Also, you seem to be ignoring how many bytes actually read. So:

```
    block := make([]byte, blockSize)
    for {
        n, err = file.Read(block)
        if n>0 {
           hash.Write(sample[:n])
        }
        if err==io.EOF {
           break
        }
        if err != nil {
            return "ERROR"
        }
    }
```

However, the following would be much more concise:

```
io.Copy(hash,file)
```

Comment: Hi, I'm only hashing part of the file because for this type of file any change will afect at least a few GB. So the chances of not catching it with 128kb every 1mb are quite small. And even if so, it's not absolutely critical.
I missed the buffer, now moved it outside but it's still using a ton of memory.
Edit: Also, not sure what you mean when you say "Also, you seem to be ignoring how many bytes actually read."

Comment: You are ignoring the return value of `Read`

Comment: Define "a ton of memory"

Comment: >30GB of memory

Comment: How do you measure that?

Comment: I just see the memory go crazy in task manager

Comment: If this is all that your program does, and if you moved buffer allocation outside the for-loop, then this code will not use that much memory. I don' t know what measure task manager shows.